# Resolve contravariant interfaces in Windsor

Tags: c#, generics

With this code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var eventProvider = new EventProvider();

        var eventHandler = new EventHandler();
        eventProvider.AddHandler(eventHandler);

        var eventInfo = new FiredEventInfo();

        Console.WriteLine("Fire without specify generic type parameter");
        eventProvider.FireEvent(eventInfo);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Fire with specify generic type parameter");
        eventProvider.FireEvent<HandledEventInfo>(eventInfo);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

interface IEventInfo { }

interface HandledEventInfo : IEventInfo { }

class FiredEventInfo : HandledEventInfo { }

interface IEventHandler<in EventInfoType>
    where EventInfoType : IEventInfo
{
    void Handle(EventInfoType eventInfo);
}

class EventHandler : IEventHandler<HandledEventInfo>
{
    public void Handle(HandledEventInfo eventInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In EventHandler.Handle(HandledEventInfo eventInfo) { ... }");
    }
}

class EventProvider
{
    IWindsorContainer _windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();

    public void AddHandler<EventInfoType>(IEventHandler<EventInfoType> eventHandler)
        where EventInfoType : IEventInfo
    {
        _windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IEventHandler<EventInfoType>>().Instance(eventHandler));
    }

    public void FireEvent<EventInfoType>(EventInfoType eventInfo)
        where EventInfoType : IEventInfo
    {
        var eventHandlers = _windsorContainer.ResolveAll<IEventHandler<EventInfoType>>();
        if (eventHandlers.LongLength > 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventHandler in eventHandlers)
            {
                eventHandler.Handle(eventInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have output

> Fire without specify generic type parameter
>
> Fire with specify generic type parameter
>
> In EventHandler.Handle(HandledEventInfo eventInfo) { ... }

How to get calling of EvenHandler without specify generic type parameter in method `FireEvent<>`?

Comment: I don't see the contravariant interface...

Comment: interface IEventHandler<in EventInfoType>?

Comment: [windsor 3+ cannot this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/castle-project-users/JaWu1RxlxVc)
it's possible with custom IHandlersFilter.

Comment: If no one has answered you before, I'll review this tomorrow... BTW, you should use better naming conventions. Generic parameters should start with *T* (t capital letter). For example, `TEventInfo`. If you don't go this way, it's hard to review your code as It's hard to distinguish actual types and generic parameters...